# Implementing pipe in c.But it is not working

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork

I am trying to implement the pipes using c language.
I am executing a loop for every command separated by a pipe by creating child process

Following is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *cmd,*splitcmd;
    int i,j,nargc=0,characters;
    char **cmdArray;
    size_t bufsize = 1024;
    int *pipefd;
    int pipeArrCount;
    pid_t pid,wpid;
    int status = 0;

    int savestdoutfd = dup(fileno(stdout));
    int savestdinfd = dup(fileno(stdin));

    cmd = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
    characters = getline(&cmd,&bufsize,stdin);
//    printf("%s%d",cmd,characters);
    if(cmd[characters-1]=='\n')
    {
//        printf("in c");
        cmd[characters-1]='\0';
        characters--;
    }

    cmdArray = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 100);
    splitcmd=strtok(cmd,"|");
//    printf("%s\n",cmd);
    while((splitcmd))
    {
        cmdArray[nargc] = splitcmd;
        if(cmdArray[nargc][(strlen(cmdArray[nargc]))-1]==' ')
            cmdArray[nargc][(strlen(cmdArray[nargc]))-1]='\0';
        printf("%d    %s",nargc,cmdArray[nargc]);
        nargc++;
        splitcmd = strtok(NULL,"|");
    }

    pipefd=(int*)malloc(2*nargc*sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n",nargc);
    pipeArrCount=2*(nargc-1);
    printf("%d\n",pipeArrCount);
    //exit(0);
    for(i=0;i<pipeArrCount;i)
    {
        printf("making pipe for process %d\n",i);
        pipe(pipefd+i);
        i=i+2;
    }


    //exit(0);
    for(i=0;i<nargc;i)
    {
        printf("parent count %d\n",i);
        if(i==0)
        {
            printf("Creating child %d\n",i);
            // As it is first process we need to make write end of the pipe as stdout.
            if ((pid=fork()) == 0)
            {
                printf("Creating first child %d for command %s\n",i,cmdArray[i]);
                printf("EXECUTING FIRST PROCESS\n");
                printf("Writing in pipe[%d]\n",2*i+1);

                //close(pipefd[0]);

                dup2(pipefd[2*i+1],fileno(stdout));
                //closing all other pipes
                for(j=0;j<(2*nargc);j++)
                {
                    //if(j!=2*i+1)
                        close(pipefd[j]);
                }
                system(cmdArray[i]);
                //dup2(savestdoutfd,fileno(stdout));
                printf("Stdout is again restored\n");
                //printf("pipe [%d] contains %d ",2*i+1,pipefd[2*i+1]);
                exit(0);
            }

        }
        else if(i!=nargc-1)
        {
            if (fork() == 0)
            {
                printf("EXECUTING MIDDLE PROCESS\n");
                printf("Command to execute %s \n",cmdArray[i]);
                printf("Reading from pipe[%d]\n",(2*(i-1)));
                printf("writing on pipe[%d]\n",(2*i)+1);
                dup2(pipefd[(2*(i-1))], 0); //Read end of the previous process pipe as stdin
                dup2(pipefd[(2*i)+1], 1); //Write end of the pipe of current process as stdout
                //closing all other pipes
                for(j=0;j<(2*nargc);j++)
                {
                    //if((j!=(2*(i-1))) && (j!=(2*i)+1))
                        close(pipefd[j]);
                }
                system(cmdArray[i]);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (fork() == 0)
            {
                printf("Creating last child %d for command %s\n",i,cmdArray[i]);
                printf("Reading from pipe[%d]\n",(2*(i-1)));

                //close(pipefd[1]);

                dup2(pipefd[(2*(i-1))],fileno(stdin)); //Read from the end of the previous process pipe as stdin
                //printf("EXECUTING LAST PROCESS\n");
                //closing all other pipes
                for(i=0;j<(2*nargc);j++)
                {
                    //if(j!=(2*(i-1)))
                        close(pipefd[j]);
                }
                dup2(savestdoutfd,fileno(stdout));
                close(savestdoutfd);
                system(cmdArray[i]);
                dup2(savestdinfd,fileno(stdin));
                close(savestdinfd);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        i=i+1;
        sleep(1);
    }
    while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0);
}
```

Not getting any output of the second command 
For now i am trying to execute this 'A | B ' type of commands
space between the command and pipes is necessary if you execute the code

Comment: Can you please be more specific ? What is expected ? What is going wrong ?

Comment: I am trying to implement unix pipe ('|') using c.

Comment: I am trying to implement unix pipe ('|') using c.for this i am using pipe() function for communication between different commands.so first of all i try to scan the command and see how many pipes do I need then I call pipe function that many times .Now for examples I have command 'cat out.c | sort' what this program does is get one pipe and parent process forks two process each for two commands first command is executed using system call but the output of this command should be at write end of pipe that is p[1] and then close all the pipes.once this is done it .......

Comment: ........ execute second command using system call and reading from read end of the pipe i.e. p[0].

Comment: Please frame the question appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not that far from a correct solution. But first some generic remarks:

- your code does not show any include : please add them
- you are casting the return values from malloc. It would be necessary in C++ but is not in C : you should write `cmd = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));`
- you could write your loops `for(i=0;i<pipeArrCount;i+=2)` removing the `i=i+2` because it is a more common usage in C, or at least `for(i=0;i<pipeArrCount;)` to avoid a warning.

Now the real cause of your problems. You allocate an array of size `2*nargc` for the pipes, but only initialize `2*(nargc-1)`. The last 2 are not initialized which should be harmless, **but you close the whole array** (`for(j=0;j<(2*nargc);j++)`. In my tests, they were at 0 (probably because of debug mode) so you were closing stdin for your childs. Just use :

```
for(j=0;j<pipeArrCount;j++)
{
        close(pipefd[j]);
}
```

That's not all. You alse have a typo in last command, you wrote `for(i=0;j<(2*nargc);j++)` with a `i` instead of a `j`. It did not close anything which  allowed the code to run with only 2 commands as noted by Kulwant Singh.

And you must also close the pipes in the parent process. The end of the program should be:

```
    //closing all pipes
    for (j=0; j<pipeArrCount; j++) {
        close(pipefd[j]);
    }
    while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes and giving the solution.
It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code. It is working for single pipes like:

```
ls | grep "a" and ls | wc.
```

It is not working for double pipes like: `ls | grep "a" | wc`.
The error is **bad file descriptor**.

I didn't debug this error, seems there is some mishandling of file descriptors in the "else if" clause. Any way your question was it is not working for single pipes like `A | B`. But it is.

Hope this helps.